# how to develop JPA bi-directional entities in spring toot

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and jpa/hibernate, please bear my inaccurate usage of the terminologies.

I have two entities: book and address. A book is published in a certain city which is stored in "address", a "address" can publish multiple books.
The DB schema for book is: id, name, author, price, addressid
schema for address: addressid, addressCountry, addressCity
The entity for book:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_book")
public class Book implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8025948150436422040L;
@Id
long id;

@Column(name = "name")
String name;

@Column(name = "author")
String author;

@Column(name = "price")
long price;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "addressid")
private Address address;
...//getter and setter
```

The entity for address

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_address")
public class Address implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3541059157210384355L;
@Id
@Column(name= "addressid")
private long addressId;

@Column(name="addresscountry")
private String addressCountry;

@Column(name="addresscity")
private String addressCity;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")
private Collection<Book> books;
...//getter setter
```

But when I call the Restful service, I get infinite loop...

[{"id":11,"name":"Java Book","author":"Jame Gosling","price":100,"address":{"addressId":1,"addressCountry":"China","addressCity":"Shanghai","books":[{"id":11,"name":"Java Book","author":"Jame Gosling","price":100,"address":...

I did some search. And my request is:
when I search a book, I can get the information: id, name, author, price, address..
And also I can query a address to get all the books the city published.
When I add Json Annotation @JsonManagedReference in address and  @JsonBackReference in book entity, I can query book but cannot get address information.

Could you please help how to solve the problems? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please have a look into the concept of `JsonView` if you don't need to return the books to an address or the other way around. Otherwise you could tweak your object annotations to return the ID or URI of the referenced entity, e.g. using HATEOAS.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. I want to return book with address, and when query an address,  list the address and all the books published from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the `@JsonIgnore` on getter for books. This will exclude the `Collection<Book> books` property from serialization the Address.

Link : [JacksonAnnotations - Faster XML Wiki](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations)

Example:

```
@JsonIgnore
public Collection<Book> getBooks() {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **@JsonIgnore**
>
> The Jackson annotation @JsonIgnore is used to tell Jackson to ignore a
>   certain property (field) of a Java object. The property is ignored
>   both when reading JSON into Java objects, and when writing Java
>   objects into JSON.

In your case this is happening as there is bidirectional relationship and so it will go into loop. To stop this you need to provide JsonIgnore

And so your code will be like :

-> The entity for address

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_address")
public class Address implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3541059157210384355L;
@Id
@Column(name= "addressid")
private long addressId;

@Column(name="addresscountry")
private String addressCountry;

@Column(name="addresscity")
private String addressCity;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<Book> books;
```

Comment: Thank you Riddhi Gohil. With @JsonIgnore can I search an address and get the address info as well as the books published from the address?